How Kafka Listener re delivers messages when started consuming messages with auto commit set to false
Let's say suppose I started my consumer with auto commit set to false and consumer started listening to the messages.

My listener processed 50 messages out of total polled as 100 and then only 50 has been committed and rest 51 to 100 are uncommitted.
And I started processing next set of messages from 101 and committed till 200.
After some time will my consumer receive messages from 51 to 100 as I didn't commit them?

How my Kafka Consumer will behave with this Use Case??
I've tried below approach. Polling messages in Batch and commit those batch of records based upon my processing result.
@KafkaListener(id="${listenerID}",topics = "${consumer.topic}", containerFactory = "listenerContainerFactory",autoStartup ="${isListenerEnabled}")
public void messageListener(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> list,Consumer<String, String> consumer) {
 try {
        Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsetAndMetadataMap=processMessage(list, acknowledgment,consumer); //Here I've logic which validates batch of records and gives result for all the processed records. 
        consumer.commitSync(offsetAndMetadataMap);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
               }
}



public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> listenerContainerFactory()
 {
 ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new  ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

      factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
      factory.setBatchListener(true); 
      factory.setAutoStartup(false); 
      factory.setConcurrency(consumerProperties.getConsumerThreads()); 
      factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(1000,2)));       
     
    if(!consumerProperties.isAutoCommit()) { 
      factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
      }
 return factory; 
}


public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() { 
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
 try {
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,bootStarpServer);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, keyDeserializer);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, valueDeserializer);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,groupId);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG,autoCommit);
      
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(properties);
    }


if your consumer had consumed messages until offset 50, the next message it would consume would be from offset 51.
Can you elaborate what you mean by consumer would process from 101-200?

From Poll I started consuming the messages as I get, I processed from 1 to 50 offset and committed. Then in next poll, I got from the 51 to 100, I didn't committed them. Then in next poll I received from 101 to 200 which I committed. What will happen to the messages from 51-100, how they will be redelivered.
What happens to the messages which aren't committed.?

No your consumer will not receive messages from offset 51 to 100 because previously you have committed offset 200 which is higher than 100 or 51.
When you commit some offset to kafka, Kafa stores this offset in specific consumer group meta.In future if some consumer connects to the consumer group then kafka will start sending messages from offset that is previosuly stored.

In my code, I've the track of each record which has been processed, based upon it I created a Map and then calling commitSync which will commit the records. How this will work then.? What is the benefit with auto commit then?
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsetAndMetadataMap=processMessage(list, acknowledgment,consumer); //Here I've logic which validates batch of records and gives result for all the processed records.
consumer.commitSync(offsetAndMetadataMap);

If you enable auto commit to true then no need to manually commit the offsets...like your maintaining map etc are not required. For every current consumer poll,consumer will commit the highest offset that it received in previous consumer poll to kafka.
